# Customizing field_with_errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, customization, formtastic, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to tell Rails to not create `div.field_with_errors` around both label and actually field, but to create `div.error` around them both?

E.g. snippet from my view with the form (written in HAML)

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  %div.clearfix
    = f.label :name
    %div.input
      = f.text_field :name
```

I want in the case of error the root div to be `div.clearfix.error` and avoid that `field_with_errors`. Can I do so?

As another option, can I make formtastic to create [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)-styled elements, w/o formtastic's css and html classes, but with bootstrap's ones. Can I make something with error fields in the case of using formtastic?

Answer (score 17):

@flowdelic's answer seems to be the simplest fix. However, the names are incorrect.
This may be due to the Rails/Bootstrap version, but this works for me.

```
/* Rails scaffold style compatibility */
#error_explanation {
  @extend .alert;
  @extend .alert-error;
  @extend .alert-block; /* optional */
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group.error
}
```

Comment: new one `@extend .alert-danger;`

Answer (score 11):

Create `config/initializers/field_with_errors.rb` with:

```rb
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  "<div class=\"error\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe
end
```

This will swap `.field-with-errors` for `.error`.

However, the biggest problem I've found with the "Rails-way" is that it wraps the element with a new `div` instead of simply adding the class to the element itself. I prefer this:

```rb
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  parts = html_tag.split('>', 2)
  parts[0] += ' class="field_with_errors">'
  (parts[0] + parts[1]).html_safe
end
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. A pity that html_tag is an ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer, basically a string variant, which makes wrapping it easy but modifying it very hard!

Comment: This is the way to go. To maintain current classes though, I use this instead:

`html_tag.gsub(/class="(.*?)"/, 'class="\1 is-invalid"')`

Answer (score 7):

if anyone uses LESS:

in bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less you can add:

```
#error_explanation {
  .alert();
  .alert-error();
  .alert-block();
}

.field_with_errors {
  .control-group.error();
}
```

which is the LESS version of the shown sass example.

Comment: In more recent Bootstrap versions, this would be: `.has-error()` instead of `.control-group.error()`.

Answer (score 5):

This is what works with Bootstrap 3, when using the https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails gem.

```
.field_with_errors {
  @include form-control-validation($state-danger-text, $state-danger-text, $state-danger-bg);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did with bootstrap 3.0.3 and rails 4.0.2:

```
/* Rails scaffold style compatibility */
#error_explanation {
  @extend .alert;
  @extend .alert-danger;
  width: inherit;
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  display: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SASS with Twitter Bootstrap, you can use the @extend directive to apply the Twitter Bootstrap styles to the Rails generated CSS classes. (Search GitHub, there are several Bootstrap/SASS ports available.)

For example:

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* Rails scaffold style compatibility */
.errorExplanation {
  @extend .alert-message;
  @extend .block-message;
  @extend .error;
}

.fieldWithErrors {
  // pulled from div.clearfix.error
  @include formFieldState(#b94a48, #ee5f5b, lighten(#ee5f5b, 30%));
}
```

Note that the Twitter Bootstrap style for 'error' is attached to a div.clearfix selector, which prevents us from simply doing this:

```
.fieldWithErrors {
  @extend .error;
}
```

So, instead, I copied/pasted the code from Bootstrap's definition for div.clearfix.error into my .fieldWithErrors selector.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 5, Rails 7.
As stated by other users, you can override this behavior by setting ActionView::Base.field_error_proc in an initializer.  As I understand it, you want something like:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc { |html| tag.div html, class: "errors" }
```

I wanted to override this to not wrap the html at all, but instead to inject 'is-invalid' into the class of the original HTML. I prefer using Nokogiri to parse it to a DomFragment and update the class that way rather than using regex.

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc do |html| 
  frag = Nokogiri::HTML5::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
  klass = frag.children[0].attributes['class']
  frag.children[0].attributes['class'].value = [klass, 'is-invalid'].join(' ')
  frag.to_html.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I came up with.

I added this to my css

```
.field_with_errors {
    display:inline;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

I added this to the `<head>`

```
$(function(){
    $('.field_with_errors').addClass('control-group error');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no enough points to comment, so I will answer here:

To add to the answer by @iosctr -- the css began to work only after I added to my `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss` file:

```
@import "bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 40px; }
@import "bootstrap-responsive";

#error_explanation {
  @extend .alert;
  @extend .alert-error;
  @extend .alert-block; 
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group.error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap 3.0, the class is `has-error`. @oded's solution should be:

```
$('.field_with_errors').parent().addClass('has-error');
```

Comment: If you use SASS: `.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It's actually more irritating than you'd think.

I ended up creating my own tag helpers (which I needed for other purposes as well), although I started with just overriding `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc`. (Which is a story unto itself since it passes in a string, not actually something you can reliably fiddle with :(

But start with that and see if it does enough for you, otherwise prepare for some digging and tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Formtastic Bootstrap](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap) gem to create Twitter Bootstrap-friendly markup with Formtastic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution for all this mess. It is javascript based but it solved my problems - just add this (when you use horizontal form):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.field_with_errors').parent().addClass('error');
});
```

It basically takes the default Rails behaviour and transform it into the Bootstrap one. Adding the error class to the `control-group` where it belongs.
No `css` and no overriding the default `field_error_proc`.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 and Rails 4 -- I had to do the following:

```
.alert-error{
    color: #f00;
    @extend .alert;
    @extend .alert-danger;
}

#error_explanation
{   ul
    {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 0 18px 0;
        color: red
    }
}

.field_with_errors
{
    input {
    border: 2px solid red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can hack out the wrapper div. Borrowing from [this tipoff](https://coderwall.com/p/s-zwrg/remove-rails-field_with_errors-wrapper) I modified it to convert the wrapper into an `invalid` class on the label and form inputs themselves...

Place this in your config somewhere (e.g. `environments.rb`)

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  (html_tag.gsub /class="(.*?)"/, 'class="\1 invalid"').html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0):

jpgeek's answer worked for me in *most* cases. However, if an `input` tag does not possess a CSS class attribute *already*, it will not work but break the application (at least in my Rails 7 app). So this is the code that works for me:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  if html_tag =~ /<(input|textarea|select)/
    html_field = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_tag)
    html_field.children.add_class("invalid")
    html_field.to_html.html_safe
  else
    html_tag
  end
end
```